# Powershell array to html

Tags: html, arrays, powershell

I've three arrays that i would like to write to a HTML page :

```
foreach($arrin $array1){

  # create TAb in html file
 }
foreach($ar in $array2){
 # create TAb in html file
 }
foreach($a in $array3){
 # create TAb in html file
 }
```

How can i do this ? THNKS

Comment: Construct the HTML in a string object then output the string to a HTML file.

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell has a built-in command to generate HTML. Try this:

```
$array | ConvertTo-Html > foo.html
```

Or if you only want certain properties in the array:

```
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html -Property Name,Id,PM
```